# Weird error in IAR EWARM "Error[Pe147]: declaration is incompatible with "__interwork __softfp"

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm getting this error that goes beyond my knowledge :

```
Error[Pe147]: declaration is incompatible with "__interwork __softfp char *Get_Language_String(enum Lang_Index, enum String_Index)" (declared at line 26 of "E:\Freescale\Freescale_MQX_4_0\demo\ E:\Freescale\Freescale_MQX_4_0\demo\DialogD13_Demo_v5\Strings.c 79
```

DialogD13_Demo_v5\Strings.h")

I have this in my code :

```
strings.h:
extern char *Get_Language_String(enum Lang_Index Lang_Ind, enum String_Index Str_Ind);

strings.c:
char *Get_Language_String(enum Lang_Index Lang_Ind, enum String_Index Str_Ind)
{
  return languages[Lang_Ind][Str_Ind];
}
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks in advance,

regards,
Bul.

Comment: Do you have both Strings.[ch] in a demo package and locally strings.[ch] files with the same prototype defined?  It's hard to tell from the question.  Also, enums can be forced to have negative values in their declaration.  If you share maintenance of those enums with others, you might want to test for that.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for response...

It was order of definitions that caused this error.

extern clause in strngs.h was before definitions of enums...

Regards,

Bulek.